# How can I force users to upload a specific/ crop to aspect ratio of photos using MediaUploader?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

I am trying to create a slider post type and I would like to crop images in a specfic aspect ratio. How can I achieve it?

```
    //Choosing slide photo in admin
$('#slide-pic-upload-btn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var mediaUploader;
    if(mediaUploader){
        mediaUploader.open();
        return;
    }

    mediaUploader= wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title:'Choose a Profile Pic',
        button:{
            text:'Choose Picture',
        },
        multiple:false
    })

    mediaUploader.on('select',function () {
        attachment=mediaUploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        $('#profile-pic').val(attachment.url)
        $('.sunset-profile-pic>img').attr("src",attachment.url)
    })

    mediaUploader.open();
})
```

Comment: Use add_image_size() function.https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/

Comment: Is it not possible to do it in javascript using the wp object?